# Attribute Error from Minimizer object returned from scipy.optimize.minimize() function

Tags: python, scipy, data-analysis, data-fitting

Using the scipy.optimize.minimize() function I went trough different results using different methods for the same objective function. To evaluate the **goodness-of-fit** I use to look at the reduced chi squared as a first criterion. After some time I ended with this useful guide http://newville.github.io/lmfit-py/fitting.html#Minimizer where it is specified that the reduced chi squared is set as attribute of the Minimizer object returned from the minimize() function. But if I do

```
minobj = scipy.optimize.minimize(...)
minobj.redchi
```

I get

```
 AttributeError: redchi
```

Meanwhile minobj.message and minobj.success are correctly displayed. 
Any guess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation is a little misleading --- if you look at `lmfit/minimizer.py`, and do a string search for "redchi" in the entire file, it only appears once, and that is in the `leastsq()` method. So basically, it only calculates the reduced chi squared for least-squares fitting.

If you're feeling up to it, you could add `redchi` to the other methods in the appropriate places, fork the lmfit github repo, and commit your changes.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I calculated it along my code, once I get the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Ashwin's answer, you could always just use:

```
result = lmfit.minimize(...)
x2 = result.chisqr
nfree = result.nfree
red_x2 = x2/nfree
```